# Node api prefix all routes with /api

Tags: node.js, express

is there a better way of prefixing all routes with /something than this?
`app.use('/api/users', require('./routes/users'));`

`app.use('/api/books', require('./routes/books'));`

`app.use('/api/authors', require('./routes/authors'));`

That would also work when using the routes in my server.js with the `app.get()/post()/...`

Answer (score 0):

If all your routes are prefixed by `/api`, I suppose you could use function.

```js
function api(route) {
  return `/api/${route}`;
}

app.use(api('users'), require('./routes/users'));
app.use(api('books'), require('./routes/books'));
app.use(api('authors'), require('./routes/authors'));
```

That being said, the `/api` prefix may be unnecessary. You could just omit it:

```js
app.use('/users', require('./routes/users'));
app.use('/books', require('./routes/books'));
app.use('/authors', require('./routes/authors'));
```

Comment: Let's say I have a website website.com and a folder that contains another website, sort of a project. So I would have website.com/project that would display the project website and website.com/project/api - that would be the path to the API I would make the requests with.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `{ mergeParams: true }` into the child router.

```js
// app.js
import routes from './routes'

const API_PREFIX = '/api'
app.use(API_PREFIX, routes)
```

```js
// routes.js
import { Router } from 'express'
import users from './users'
import books from './books'
import authors from './authors'

const router = Router({ mergeParams: true })

router.use(users)
router.use(books)
router.use(authors)

export default router
```